# Read from Stringlist as read from a File

Tags: delphi

I have a function which works on reading data from a file like :

```
procedure ReadDatafromFile (const aFilename : String; aparameterList : TList );
var  aIniFile : TInifile;
 begin
     aIniFile :=TInifile.create(aFilename);
    data1 :=  ReadInteger(......);
    .....
     ....
 end;
```

Now the contents of this file exists at a different location in my program as a StringList. I would like to reuse the existing code, and I would like to program it in a way like:

```
...
MydataStringList.SaveToFile('c:\temp\tempfile.txt');
ReadDatafromFile( MydataStringList, myparameterList);
...
```

Is there any smart solution to reuse the existing function and create an overloaded version which is accepting the StringList as a parameter?

Comment: Your edit makes this question really unclear. You were talking about a StringList, now it's about an IniFile! How relates the IniFile to the StringList? Do you use `aIniFile.GetStrings(MydataStringList)`? Then how should the new routine (with the StringList parameter) parse the StringList contents to the aParameterList? Is there even need to parse from the IniFile? Why don't you just store the IniFile instead of the StringList? There's such a thing like TMemIniFile you know? We need to see more code, or you need to be more clear on - well - everything.

Comment: Apparently, you seem to have code for parsing from a IniFile to a StringList (_Now the contents of this file exists at a different location in my program as a StringList_). Why do you need code to parse from IniFile to aParemeterList then? Or even better, like meant above: why the StringList? Store the IniFile.

Answer (score 3):

That is doable:

```
procedure ReadDataFromStrings(aFileStrings: TStrings; aParameterList: TList);
  overload;
begin
  if aParameterList <> nil then
    // Add aFileStrings to aParameterList
end;

procedure ReadDataFromFile(const aFileName: TFileName; aParameterList: TList);
  overload;
var
  Strings: TStringList;
begin
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strings.LoadFromFile(aFileName);
    ReadDataFromStrings(Strings, aParameterList);
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Instead of creating this local `Strings` variable, you could also use the already present global `MydataStringList` variable, whichever suits your needs.

Comment: +1 (and deleting my answer). You caught the "overload" part and answered it; I missed it. Very nice.

Comment: I changed the Q, hope it is now more clear. I assume I must do something like a virtual file , created with my Stringlist. Proposed solution above will force me to double the code , read from string list and read from file

Comment: @Franz This is the answer to your question!

Comment: The question is not `how to read file to string list` but `is it possible to load data from stringlist directly in inifile or read it with inifile interface from stringlist`